# Can a forced runner be tagged out when standing on base?

Tags: rules, softball

Runner on first and runner on second, no outs. Ball is hit to shortstop but the runner on second stays on base.

Can SS just tag the runner who is still standing on second base, then touch second base to force out the runner going from first to second?

My thought is that the runner on second is forced off base and can now be tagged out even though they are still standing on second base as they are forced off base.

Answer (score 4):

> Can SS just tag runner who is still standing on 2nd base?

Yes.  The ball in play makes that runner no longer entitled to second base.   While the force is in play, tagging the runner at any point before the runner reaches third base would be a force out.

Not sure what league you're interested in, but [NCAA softball rule](https://www.ncaapublications.com/p-4639-2022-and-2023-ncaa-womens-softball-rules.aspx) has:

> 19.9.2.1 A runner is considered forced out if they must advance to the next
> base or to home plate in order to make room for another runner, but:
>
> 12.9.2.1.1 They are legally tagged as in Rule 12.9.1 before they reach the
> forced base.

Standing on second, the runner has not reached the forced base (third) and is out.

(For a league just using [MLB rules](https://img.mlbstatic.com/mlb-images/image/upload/mlb/wqn5ah4c3qtivwx3jatm.pdf), this is found in 5.09(b)(6).)

> Then touch 2nd base to force out runner going from 1st to 2nd?

If done before the runner reaches second base, that's correct.

And the order is important.  If the first action of SS is to step on second base, the runner from first is out and the force on the runner from second is removed.  The runner from second would then be safe at second base if tagged.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following NCAA rules:

19.9.2.1 A runner is considered forced out if they must advance to the next base or to home plate in order to make room for another runner, but:

12.9.2.1.1 They are legally tagged as in Rule 12.9.1 before they reach the forced base.

Rule12.9.2.1.1 references 12.9.1 Tag Play which states “A runner is considered tagged out if the ball is in play and she is not in contact with a base when she is legally touched by the ball securely held in the hand(s) or legal glove/mitt of a fielder.”

Note that a legal tag requires the runner to not be in contact with a base when the runner is legally touched. Based on this rule, I would conclude the runner standing on 2nd base cannot be tagged out and can only be put out by forcing her out by touching 3rd base or by tagging her if and when she moves off 2nd base.

Comment: I don't see what this adds to the existing answer.

Comment: The first answer argues the runner standing on 2nd base can be put out when tagged while standing on the base in a force out situation. Based on the NCAA definition of a legal tag, I am arguing the runner cannot be tagged out if still standing on 2nd base.